# iOS - EncodeWithCoder - Encode Nil

Tags: ios, nscoding, uidocument

I have an object that has a property that might be nil. How should I implement this in encodeWithCoder (and decodeWithCoder)?

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{ 
    [aCoder encodeObject:_duration forKey:kDuration]; //_duration could be nil
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{ 
    if (_duration) {
        [aCoder encodeObject:_duration forKey:kDuration]; //_duration could be nil
    }
}
```

(Your object will be `nil` on decode if the key is not present.)

Answer (score 14):

Aaron's solution is clean and clearly communicates what's going on. I couldn't find any information, however, whether it's OK to pass `nil` to `encodeObject:forKey:`, so I tested it. It turns out that you can safely do so (please correct me if I'm missing something).

So you can simply say

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{ 
    [aCoder encodeObject:_duration forKey:kDuration]; //_duration could be nil
}
```

Even when _duration is nil, this will work. It will simply not write the key to the coder in that case.

Comment: Note that this will *overwrite* the old value of `_duration` with `nil`, which may not be desirable. That is, you might want to encode the value only if it's present in order to preserve an older value.